# Sinon unit testing. How to unit test a function that will call a async function then calls a function which will return a call back?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, ava

I have a function I need to test, it first calls a async function, once received the response then returns a promise to call another function will callback.. Below is the function that I need to write test case for:

```
const bookService = require('./bookService');
const libraryService = require('./libraryService');

const findBook = (bookName) => {
  libraryService.getAllBooks().then(res => {
    if(res.length > 0){
      //find book code based on bookName in res....
    bookCode = ...;
   
    const url = bookService.getBookUrl(bookCode) + '/booksystem?bookcode=' + bookCode;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bookService.InfoRequest(bookCode, url, {}, 'GET', res => {
      if(res.error){
         reject(res);
      }else{
         //Do things here...
         resolve(res)
      }
    })
  })
  }
})
}
```

I have tried stub the bookService.InfoRequest method, but it keeps giving me 1 uncaught exception says :

```
SyntaxError: The URL '/booksystem?bookcode=' is invalid..
```

I try to console log the url in the code, it prints out ok. But unit test case giving me uncaught exception.

I am using Ava, so I tried something like this:

```
test('find Book positive test', t => {
  sandbox.stub(libraryService, 'getAllBooks').resolves([
   {Name : 'book1', Code : 'b1'}, 
   {Name : 'book2', Code : 'b2'},
   {Name : 'book3', Code : 'b3'}
 ]);
  const testRes = [
   {bookCode: 'b1', price : 10},
   {bookCode: 'b2', price : 20},
   {bookCode: 'b3', price : 30}
];
  const stubBookService = sandbox.stub(bookService, 'InfoRequest');
  stubBookService.callsFake((bookCode, url, {}, method, callback) => {
    callback(testRes);
})


  api.findBook('book1');

})
```

api is the module that I am testing. Also in this case, what is the best way to assert? Thank you

Comment: Are you not planning return the `libraryService.getAllBooks()` promise in `findBook` function?

Comment: Do I have to? I did't return it works just fine...Let me know if I am wrong

Comment: If you don't, how do you make sure the `api.findBook()` method is completed in the test case? You don't need any return value?